# Scala Dynamic Tracing

Tags: scala, trace

I'm solving a problem about scala tracing.
What I want to do is get the environment after executing each line of a scala file, which means, for a program in scala, I could know which line it is executing now and the variables existing now, for every line.
Now I'm using the method of stepping. I let the program step into or step return automatically(by editting the scala IDE in Eclipse) for every line, and then I could get what we want.
But for a long program, it's very slow and will cost a large amount of memory, more than 20GB!
So do you have any better idea about how to achieve it?Give me the whole trace in source code format for every line of a program, with source file path, line number and current variables.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no free/opensource tools for the task you described, only commercial ones:

- [Chronon](http://chrononsystems.com/what-is-chronon/technology), but looks like that only Java is supported.
- [Jidebug](http://www.jidebug.com/), I also not sure about Scala.

They both can record runtime traces of your JVM code and later you can drill into these to understand what has happened there.